# TABLE LOCK Read Write ALIAS

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get this to work but get an error `t_write was not locked.`

I'm updating the col `make` and the col `sn` from the highest value `sn + 1`

```
LOCK TABLES 1_makes AS t_read READ, 1_makes as t_write WRITE;

UPDATE t_write 
SET 
    make = 'Pioneer',
    sn = (SELECT 
            *
        from
            (SELECT 
                MAX(sn)
            FROM
                t_read
            WHERE
                id <> 0) as new_sn) + 1
WHERE
    id = 2;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
LOCK TABLES 1_makes WRITE, 1_makes AS t_read READ;

UPDATE 1_makes
SET 
    make = 'Pioneer',
    sn = (SELECT 
            *
        from
            (SELECT 
                MAX(sn)
            FROM
                1_makes AS t_read
            WHERE
                id <> 0) as new_sn) + 1
WHERE
    id = 2;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works a treat.

Comment: If answer is helpful, may I suggest accepting it? ) First, it might save some time for some other guys; second, we both get some nice points boost. )

Comment: Is it possible to "tell" MySql to do this automatically each time on `UPDATE` (without using `trigger`)? Or will I have to implement this in my PHP-query?

Comment: Why, but you just described a trigger here! The only alternative I see is using stored procedure (instead of plain UPDATE).