# MySql unique index over two colums - auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql two column primary key with auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment)

I've got the following table with a `UNIQUE` key over two columns:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pa_id        | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| FK_languages | tinyint(2)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| pa_attribute | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Right now, I've got the following entries:

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+
| pa_id | FK_languages | pa_attribute |
+-------+--------------+--------------+
|     1 |            1 | white        |
|     1 |            2 | weiß         |
+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

Let's say, I want to insert a new entry "black" with `FK_languages = 1`... what is the best practice to `auto increment` col "pa_id" that it will look like this:

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+
| pa_id | FK_languages | pa_attribute |
+-------+--------------+--------------+
|     2 |            1 | black        |
+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

**NOTE** Unfortunateley I cannot use the `TRIGGER` function of MySql. Is it possible to do this nevertheless via MySql? I would like to avoid doing this via my scripting-language (PHP).

**EDIT:**

It seems I can only solve this issue via my query in PHP. The assumed duplicate thread only offers two solutions: MyISAM or Innodb + trigger. Neither will work with me.

Comment: I'm using INNODB. The suggested thread seems to offer only a solution via TRIGGER, which I cant' use.

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990044/table-lock-read-write-alias) then.

Comment: Thanks. Asked a question in comment of accepted answer there... :)

Comment: You're using InnoDB, but why not switch this table to MyISAM?

Comment: Cause of Foreign_keys, Cascading (on delete) etc.